# Macbook Pro Battery Condition: Replace Now

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

My Macbook Pro ( Retina 13 inch early 2015), all of a sudden, started showing "Condition: Replace Now" on battery. Everything was working fine till last night; when I turned on the laptop in the morning, it asked me to restore the work (as if it was crashed when I turned it off at night).

The laptop was slow, and I noticed this "Condition: Replace Now" on battery status. I shut down the laptop, rebooted, did SMC reset, PRAM reset, but its still showing the same. The battery is showing 0% when I remove the charger the laptop turned off. And when its off when I connect the charger its starts the laptop.

My battery cycle is just 385. I am running macOS Sierra. Can anyone please advise what is the workaround to fix this.

Comment: Double-check with [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) (freeware) If it concurs, you need a new battery.

Comment: @Tetsujin just downloaded, it says macOS battery status = Poor
Charging with = 0 Watts
Power adapter = Connected

Comment: tbh, I'm not sure what that indicates. I'd wait to see if someone with better specific knowledge comes along, but I'd be prepared to take a trip to an Apple Store sometime soon.

Comment: Batteries die - sometime prematurely, but they do die.  The solution here (as in the dupe link) is to replace the battery.